# PlayerPrefab's `Start()` is being called before play scene's `Awake()`

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-unet

I'm using Unity's [Network Lobby](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/41836) asset to create a lobby for my game. The game's working fine on editor, but when I build to PC something weird happens: The `Start()` function of the first player object is being called before the `Awake()` of everything else within the scene.

I'm having trouble debugging because the bug only happen on PC builds. But I believe currently the script execution order is something like:

First player's `Start()` -> all `Awake()` within game scene -> other players' `Start()`

Please help me make first's player `Start()` execute when it should normally!

Comment: how about: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour.OnStartClient.html

Comment: or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkBehaviour.OnStartLocalPlayer.html

Comment: @CổChíTâm doesn't seems like what I'm trying to do, or maybe I'm just not using it correctly...

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You may change scripts execution order [Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html).
Also you may check methods call order for Unity Networking [Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html)